# PHP json_encoded message match with java json object

Tags: java, php, android, json, response

I'm trying to make response listener for my Android app.

I'm trying to get a response from my php code likes this:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray success = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("success");
            JSONArray success2 = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("no");
            if (success.toString() == "{"success"}") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EnglishRegisterSite.this, UK.class);
                EnglishRegisterSite.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (success2.toString() == "{"no"}") {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnglishRegisterSite.this);
                builder.setMessage("You are not 18 years old! kid!")
                       .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                       .create()
                       .show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
};
```

The PHP response looks like this:

```
$response = array();
$response["no"];  
echo json_encode($response);
```

If I change the php array to `$response["no"] = true;` and make a boolean then I can get it to work like this:

```
 boolean success2 = jsonResponse.getboolean("no");
```

but this won't do because then I can only have two scenarios. Either failed or succeeded. But what I am trying to achieve is creating more scenarios stating like if it fails then specify why it fails. Like in this example. If the user is trying to register and is not 18 years old yet then pop up a message stating that is the problem.

Therefor I need to send some kind of JSON encoded message from PHP to Java that I in Java can check up on.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try json response content like this:

```
{
    success: true,
    msg: "Here can be anything you want to display."
}
```

If success is true, then register, else display msg content.